# Converting UTF-8 Characters in urls for SQL Query in PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, utf-8

I am running a SQL query on a Wordpress blog to a get json feed of posts.  Here is my code:  http://pastebin.com/jvaM9ySr

It works fine but some of the post url's are coming through with what I think are UTF-8 special characters like

```
ranking-of-the-country%e2%80%99s-101-best-desserts
```

where I guess a blog editor pasted in a fancy apostrophe.

other examples have %e2%84%a2 in the middle of the url for the trademark symbol and even %cf%83 for the greek sigma letter.

I'd like to convert these to show what the actual special character is in the json feed.

I am using this to [match the urls in the Google Analytics API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13575576/join-two-associative-arrays-with-php) and the corresponding Analytics urls contain the special character itself and not code like:

```
 ranking-of-the-country’s-101-best-desserts
```

so these few cases aren't matching because of this special character issue.

I've tried to use utf8_encode and utf8_decode in various places in the code that is in the pastebin with no luck.

Any one have any ideas?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have had the similar problem like you in another programming language.

This is not `utf8 encode` but `url encode`.

Try to use:

```
urlencode(string)
```

and

```
urldecode(string)
```

In the 2 cases (with decoding all the `%char` change with the correct utf char).

Here you can find more information and examples: http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

**UPDATE**:
for your code: I haven't tested, but you must or decoding the url when you store the response value here

```
    while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($sth)) {
    if $r is a url
    $rows = decode($r);
    else
    $rows[] = $r;   
    }
```

OR
differentiate the printing at the end of your code (something like the code before): doing for each variable in the array the appropriate printing (and when you "catch" the "url" you do the decoding), here:

```
print strip_tags(json_encode($rows));
```

Comment: `echo urldecode("ranking-of-the-country%e2%80%99s-101-best-desserts");` works perfectly!  thanks!

Comment: Would you mind taking a look at my [code](http://pastebin.com/jvaM9ySr) and letting me know where you think the `urldecode();`should go?  Anywhere I try either turns the json feed into NULL or doesn't do anything at all.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure why but it looks like this is working for me! 
`print strip_tags(rawurldecode(json_encode($rows)))`

Answer (score 0):

All you need is

```
$text = "ranking-of-the-country%e2%80%99s-101-best-desserts";
echo 'TRANSLIT : ', iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT", $text), PHP_EOL;
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer but I don't think this will work.  When I put your two lines into http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/ it just echos back the original string?